# [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. Error

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-mix

I'm trying to build a Vue app, but I am getting this error on the console:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

This is my code:

`header.vue`

```html
<header>
    <div class="page-logo">Foo.com</div>
</header>
<nav>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>My Account</li>
        <li>Log In</li>
        <li>Log Out</li>
        <li>Sign Up</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

This is my `app.js`:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import $ from 'jquery'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

var App = (function (App) {
    App.appComp = {
        header : Vue.component('mainMenu', require('./components/app/header.vue'))
    };
    const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {
          path: '/',
          components: {
            header: App.appComp.header,
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    App.app = new Vue({
        router
    }).$mount('#app');
    return App;
})(App || {});
```

And I'm trying to build this with laravel Mix.
But I get this error in the console:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.
>   found in  --->  at  /opt/lampp/htdocs/gif/resources/assets/js/components/app/header.vue

I searched in google and I found this answer: [Vue template or render function not defined yet I am using neither?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983767/vue-template-or-render-function-not-defined-yet-i-am-using-neither)

So I've tried to override the definition in mix. I did:

```js
 mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js' // 'vue/dist/vue.common.js' for webpack 1
        }
    }
});
```

That didn't work, so I tried to change the webpack config file

I found there this line:

```js
 module.exports.resolve = {
     extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.vue'],

    alias: {
         'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
    }
};
```

I tried to replace common with esm, didn't help.

What else should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML in a single file component needs to be wrapped in `template` tags.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <header>
      <div class="page-logo">Foo.com</div>
    </header>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li>My Account</li>
        <li>Log In</li>
        <li>Log Out</li>
        <li>Sign Up</li>
       </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
<template>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, it works, but just that you know, you can't have two root elements inside the template tag, you need to wrap them with `div`, I learn that when I got an error while adding the `template` tag

Comment: @NatiV Thats true! I'll add a div to the answer. I should have caught that /facepalm