# Unable to import and use vuejs single-file-component after build

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I'm trying to reuse some of my components from one repository in another one. My component is a single file component. I setup webpack to create a .js bundle for that component and then I copy that file and drop it in the other repository's shared directory.

when I import that component and register it in the repository it was created in, there is no issue. Problem is when I import that component and register it on a parent component after I bundle it (separately) and move it to the other repository. I'm getting this error message.

> Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

Export file

```
<template>
   // template code
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
        data: 'data'
    }
},
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Import file:

```
import sharedComponent from '../../components/shared/sharedComponent.vue';

Vue.component('parent-component', {
   components:{
    'shared-component': sharedComponent,
   },
})
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Your `parent-component` has neither a template or render function.

Comment: Parent component was rendering properly before I registered child component.

Comment: Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52495768/13602136
, or use `require().default` instead of  `import`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58326981/13602136

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that worked for me:

The issue seemed to be happening because of the way webpack was bundling the file. Fixed by explicitly requesting umd build in the webpack configuration as such:

```
output: {
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
},
```