# Property or method "posts" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to replicate the vue tutorial example (found here: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#passing-data-to-child-components-with-props ), but with no success. Below is my code. I have a view called TA.vue, that i would like to import the component into and render. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

TA.vue (the view):

```
<template id="front">
    <b-container style="margin-top: 9rem;">
        <b-row>
            <div id="blog-posts-events-demo" class="demo">
                <div>
                    <blog_post
                        v-for="post in posts"
                        :key="post.id"
                        :title="post.title"
                    ></blog_post>
                </div>
            </div>
        </b-row>

    </b-container>

</template>

<script>
import blog_post from '../components/blog_post' // import the Header component
  export default {
    name: 'talent-acquisition',
    components: {
        blog_post
    }
  }
</script>
```

blog_post component:

```
Vue.component('blog_post', {
    el: '#front',
    
    data() {
        return {
            posts: [
                { id: 1, title: 'My journey with Vue'},
                { id: 2, title: 'Blogging with Vue'},
                { id: 3, title: 'Why Vue is so fun'}
            ]
        }
    },
  props: ['title'],
  template: `
    <div class="blog_post">
      <h4>{{ title }}</h4>
    </div>
  `
})

app.mount('#blog-posts-events-demo')
```

EDIT:
After following Amaarrockz suggestion, I have the following error:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <BlogPost> at src/components/blog_post.vue
       <TalentAcquisition>
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is you have array 'posts' defined in your child component('blog_post') which you are trying to iterate from the parent.
The better implementation would be to define the array in the parent component .
Please find the modifications below

TA.vue

```
<template id="front">
    <b-container style="margin-top: 9rem;">
        <b-row>
            <div id="blog-posts-events-demo" class="demo">
                <div>
                    <blog_post
                        v-for="post in posts"
                        :key="post.id"
                        :title="post.title"
                    ></blog_post>
                </div>
            </div>
        </b-row>

    </b-container>

</template>

<script>
import blog_post from '../components/blog_post' // import the Header component
  export default {
    name: 'talent-acquisition',
    components: {
        blog_post
    },
data() {
        return {
            posts: [
                { id: 1, title: 'My journey with Vue'},
                { id: 2, title: 'Blogging with Vue'},
                { id: 3, title: 'Why Vue is so fun'}
            ]
        }
    },
  }
</script>
```

blog_post component:

```
Vue.component('blog_post', {
    el: '#front',
  props: ['title'],
  template: `
    <div class="blog_post">
      <h4>{{ title }}</h4>
    </div>
  `
})

app.mount('#blog-posts-events-demo')
```

Comment: Thanks, I am getting a new error now, I have edited it the original question now, can you check it out please

Comment: I don't see your update in the qsn, it still remains the same

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the comment before editing, take a look now please

Comment: Please check this link and see if this would help..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983767/vue-template-or-render-function-not-defined-yet-i-am-using-neither

Comment: Btw I hope that my solution helped you figure out the first problem so please do upvote and accept.. This will not only help other people with the same issue but it will also mean people are more likely to help you in the future with any other issues you have.

Comment: Agreed, I will ask this as a different question. Im not fully understanding how to apply what is suggested in the link. I think the brain is fried at the moment...

Comment: Ya that would be better..pls do give an upvote as well thx :)

Comment: Another opportunity for points ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65746235/failed-to-mount-component-template-or-render-function-not-defined-component-fa

Comment: Hope you got that answered too :)