# Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. Component fails to import

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli

I am trying to replicate the vue tutorial example (found here: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#passing-data-to-child-components-with-props ), but with no success. Below is my code. I have a view called TA.vue, that i would like to import the component into and render. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

TA.vue (the view):

```
<template id="front">
    <b-container style="margin-top: 9rem;">
        <b-row>
            <div id="blog-posts-events-demo" class="demo">
                <div>
                    <blog_post
                        v-for="post in posts"
                        :key="post.id"
                        :title="post.title"
                    ></blog_post>
                </div>
            </div>
        </b-row>

    </b-container>

</template>

<script>
import blog_post from '../components/blog_post' // import the Header component
  export default {
    name: 'talent-acquisition',
    components: {
        blog_post
    },
    data() {
        return {
            posts: [
                { id: 1, title: 'My journey with Vue'},
                { id: 2, title: 'Blogging with Vue'},
                { id: 3, title: 'Why Vue is so fun'}
                ]
            }
        },
  }

</script>
```

blog_post component:

```
Vue.component('blog_post', {
    props: ['title'],
    template: `
        <div class="blog_post">
            <h4>{{ title }}</h4>
        </div>
    `
})

app.mount('#blog-posts-events-demo')
```

Full error message:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <BlogPost>
       <TalentAcquisition> at src/views/TA.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `blog_post` file is using CDN syntax instead of CLI syntax and so isn't exporting a component.  Additionally, it tries to mount an entirely new Vue app.

Since you're using Vue CLI with single file components, all your components need to have a similar format to your *TA.vue* component.  So `blog_post` should look like this:

```html
<template>
  <div class="blog_post">
    <h4>{{ title }}</h4>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  props: ['title']
}
</script>
```