# cannot dynamically create and add Vue components failed to mount component template or render function not defined

Tags: vue.js

I've run through many different Stackoverflow posts and many had my symptoms yet none of the solutions fixed my problem.  Apparently, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983767/vue-template-or-render-function-not-defined-yet-i-am-using-neither) many, many things can cause this issue.  I decided to upgrade all my npm, node and vue to the latest and make a minimal code example of my problem (the Condition component contains a template with a single root div containing 3 vuetify text fields):

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-btn @click="addCondition()" color="secondary" dark>Add Condition</v-btn>
    <div id="conditions">
      <template v-for="condition in conditions">
        <component :is="condition" :key="condition.id"></component>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// none of the below work
//import Condition from '@/components/Condition.vue';
//const Condition = require('@/components/Condition.vue').default
Vue.component('Condition', require('@/components/Condition.vue').default);
import Vue from "vue";

export default {
  name: "Test",
  components:
  {
    Condition
  },
  methods: {
    addCondition()
    {
      const ConditionClass = Vue.extend(Condition);
      const conditionInstance = new ConditionClass(); //{ propsData: { id: conditions.length, value: 0 }});
      this.conditions.push(conditionInstance);
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      conditions: []
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

When I click the Add Condition button, I get the oft encountered and dreaded "[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined." message in the console.  Realizing that the error may be caused by things in my configuration, I also put all the code for the vue project in https://github.com/mentaloaf/stackoverflow_vuejs.git.  As I've lost a day on this I'm hoping there's a silly/simple fix.

Also thought I would post relevant toolchain versions:

```
/tmp/comptest/stackoverflow_vuejs master ?1 ❯ vue -V                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        3m 30s
@vue/cli 4.5.12
/tmp/comptest/stackoverflow_vuejs master ?1 ❯ npm -v
7.5.4
/tmp/comptest/stackoverflow_vuejs master ?1 ❯ node -v
v15.9.0
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are instantiating the component and sending that instance to your dynamic component, instead of that you should be registering the component (you are already doing that) and for your dynamic component you need to send only the name of the registered component.

The component registration is happening here:

```
Vue.component('Condition', require('@/components/Condition.vue').default);
```

In order to use that component in a dynamic manner you only need to do:

```
<component :is="'Condition'"/>
```

as you can see, only the name is needed (as a string) and Vue make the instance of the component.

Here is your code working:

```
<template>
 <div id="app">
  <v-btn @click="addCondition()" color="secondary" dark>Add Condition</v-btn>
  <div id="conditions">
   <template v-for="condition in conditions">
     <component :is="condition" :key="condition.id"></component>
   </template>
  </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
// This component registration only needs to happens once, it could also be in another file
Vue.component("Condition", require("@/components/Condition.vue").default);
import Vue from "vue";

export default {
  name: "Test",
  components: {}, // No need for the component here since you are not using it
  methods: {
    addCondition() {
      // NO need for instances here, nor for Vue.extend because Condition is already a component
      this.conditions.push("Condition");
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      conditions: [],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: First, thank you for your feedback!  I should have mentioned that I did this and it worked as you show - without the code that I thought would create a new instance each  time it was called:

Comment: const ConditionClass = Vue.extend(Condition);
      const conditionInstance = new ConditionClass();

Comment: If I continue to call this.conditions.push("Condition"), it says there is a duplicate key.  What I ultimately want to do is create many and possibly different components with different ids so I can access their individual states at the time my form is "submitted".  So I  may add 3 Condition components, 2 components of some other type, etc.  Of course, I would probably call the data property "components" or something more generic than "conditions" since it could contain any number of any type of component.  Thoughts?

Comment: In the same way that you call `conditions.push('Condition')` you can call `conditions.push('Other_Component_Registered_Name')`. For the **duplicated key error** it is because you are using the same key in the `v-for` you are using `condition.id` but that value doesn't exist (because conditions is an array of strings) you need to provide a unique id, your array could change for: `conditions.push({component:'Component', id:'some unique id'})` and in your template you change: `<component :is="condition.component" :key="condition.id"></component>`

Comment: Hi Roberto.  I used your code as is and the new Condition components that each have three text boxes do show up as I had seen when I previously used this approach in the past.  However, the conditions array is just an array containing the string "Condition" for each condition that was added.  How would I access the data in each text field from my app?  A bonus question - is it possible to have a components placeholder like I do which can contain mixed component types (at a minimum I assume I couldn't have the :is="condition" there since not every component would be a Condition component)?  Thx

Comment: The cleaner way for obtaining data from a child component, is the component emiting events and the parent listening to those events (check the docs on this). For the "bonus", the tag `component` is exactly a placeholder for components (unless I'm missing something from the question), the attribute `is` could be a reactive value and with that, it could change to any component

Comment: From what I can tell, emitting an event from the child component to the parent is the only way to transfer state.  In the vuejs docs for emitting a value with an event, it looks like I would emit an entire object containing the state of all 3 text fields and the id of the object to the parent.  My question now is - how do I dynamically create components and set their state, including the id?  I tried code like this:

Comment: this.conditions.push({ id: 0, value: 0, minValue: 0, maxValue: 99 });

Comment: Where the Condition.vue now has all those values as props and I get a render function not found error when the push of the props object is called.  I see lots of examples of having predefined components with static sets of ids when you know the number of components but none where you can create them on the fly like above.  I've also seen what feels like a hack using the ref tag and then accessing the data of the child using the DOM, but I'm not sure how that would work when I have a dynamic number of components.

Comment: I think that you need to make a new question since this is already off topic, so you can put your new code with the new problems (feel free to add a comment and tagging me on that question).

Your code was already working with dynamic components and I'm assuming that maybe you are missing something simple in the template with your new changes