# Created a dynamic component, VUE works but prints an warning "template or render function not defined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm creating a dynamic markdown component like this

```
<div v-highlight :is="markdownComponent"></div>
```

And in computed:

```
computed: {
    markdownComponent() {
      return {
        template: this.html,
        data() {
          return {}
        },
        methods: { }
      }
    }
  }
```

`this.html` is dynamically created with markdown-it. I've created a code_block/fence rule to enhance the `pre > code` block. An example of the `this.html` is:

```
<div>
    <div class="code-header">
        <span class="code-language">
            Python
        </span>
        <a class="code-copy" @click="copyText('xxxx')">
        <i class="fa fa-copy"></i>
            Copy
        </a>
    </div>
  <pre>highlighted data</pre>
</div>
```

It works but VUE prints an warning

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <Anonymous>
       <Notes2> at src/note.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

If I add a empty render function the warning will be gone but the page is also emptied:

```
computed: {
    markdownComponent() {
      return {
        render(h) {
           return h('div', {}, [])
        },
        template: this.html,
        data() {
          return {}
        },
        methods: { }
      }
    }
  }
```

}

How can I add a "default" render function? I need to make the page render correctly while stop VUE from printing that warning.

**EDIT**

I've already checked [Vue template or render function not defined yet I am using neither?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983767/vue-template-or-render-function-not-defined-yet-i-am-using-neither) it doesn't provide a solution to this problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue template or render function not defined yet I am using neither?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983767/vue-template-or-render-function-not-defined-yet-i-am-using-neither)

Comment: geauser is probably right. What is `this.html` - where does it come from and how does it look like ? Also add proper tag for version of Vue you are using...

Comment: @MichalLevý It's dynamically created from markdown-it. I just need to add a copy button to the "pre > code" element. I've attached an example to the question

Comment: Now, check which Vue package [you are using](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only)

Comment: On another note @daisy instead of creating a new component for your markdown corpus, you could simply modify the `innerHTML` of an existing element. I'll probably make your code clearer.

Comment: @geauser Problem is `this.html` does not contain pure HTML (see the `@click` handler). The `template` needs to be used here and thus, full build of Vue with the compiler is needed...

Comment: @MichalLevý Now I think geauser is right .... I've removed the click handler in code_block rules, only adding an data-src attribute. The final solution is to use v-html and add a global click handler on the markdown body. Then I check if data-src attribute is present, if it's present I'll do the clipboard copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this problem

In markdownComponent:

```
markdownComponent() {
  let html = this.html

  return {
    render(h) {
      return h('div', {
        domProps: {
          innerHTML: html
        },
        on: {
          click: this.clickHandler
        },
      })
    },
    data() {
      return {}
    },
    methods: {
      clickHandler(event) {
        let b64data = event.target.getAttribute('data-src')
        let data = Base64.decode(b64data).trim()
        this.$copyText(data)
      },
    }
  }
}
```

In code_block/fence rules, remove @click handler and add a HTML attribute instead.

And VUE no longer complains ..

Answer (score 0):

It may not seem so but [Vue template or render function not defined yet I am using neither?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983767/vue-template-or-render-function-not-defined-yet-i-am-using-neither) really solves your problem...

[Runtime + Compiler vs. Runtime-only](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only)

It is important to understand that Vue templates are **always compiled** into pure JavaScrit (just try to paste your `this.html` sample into [vue-compiler-online](https://magiccwl.github.io/vue-compiler-online/). As you are using `vue` files, you are probably using some bundler (Webpack for example - directly or via VueCLI) which is using `vue-loader` to do this compilation at build time. That's why Vue projects are usually using Vue build which does not includes template compiler.

**BUT** if you somewhere use `template` (even in such project), you need Vue package with compiler...

On the other hand, if only "Vue" functionality in the render output of markdown-it is the `@click` handler, you can do it without `template` (and without the overhead of Vue compiling perfectly static HTML produced by markdown-it into JS and then render it as static HTML again)

1. Remove your `code_block/fence` modification
2. Create a proper `markdownComponent.vue` (see below)
3. If the markdown comes from untrusted source (user) and you are passing `html:true` into markdown-it constructor, do [proper sanitization of the markdown-it output](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it/issues/427)
4. Render HTML produced by markdown-it with [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="code-header">
        <span class="code-language">
            Python
        </span>
        <a class="code-copy" @click="copyText(html)">
        <i class="fa fa-copy"></i>
            Copy
        </a>
    </div>
    <pre v-html="html"></pre>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  props: ['html'],
  methods: {
    copyText() {
      .....
    }
  }
}
<script>
```