# Laravel 9: How to rebuild Javascript files in a project

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have created a Laravel 9 project recently on mac. I am trying to use Vue components in my project. The Laravel installation comes with a Vue component (js/Components/ExampleComponenets.vue). I included the **example-component** in a view file, and the page displays the component correctly.

I made a copy of this component as js/Components/NoteComponent.vue and updated app.js to register the new component as 'note-component'

```
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('note-component', require('./components/NoteComponent.vue').default);
```

However, when I used the  **note-component** in my view file, it displays error:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <note-component> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

(found in <Root>)
```

I removed the note-component from my view file and made a change to the console.log used in the ExampleComponent.vue, but surprisingly, the page continues to display the old message. I am getting an impression that somehow the application continues to use the **old js** files, and I need to do something to **rebuild/regresh** the js files. (php artisan clear:cache) did not help.

Can someone please advise how to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `npm run dev` on your dev machine. And read the documentation on [Compiling Assets](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mix)

Comment: @brombeer, your suggestion did the trick. I did try this command earlier, bit it did not work as npm was not installed on mac. Besides, I am very new to mac. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need use npm run dev to start your vue server and remember, js is loaded when page was stored in browser memory, so do a full reload

- Command + Shift + R in mac
- CTRL + Shift + F5 in windows

Answer (score 0):

We updated to Laravel to v9 recently and had to modify the js files in this way:

```js
import Vue from "vue";

Vue.component("example", () => import("./components/ExampleComponent"));
```

Source: [Vue template or render function not defined yet I am using neither?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983767/vue-template-or-render-function-not-defined-yet-i-am-using-neither)